# Why does the KML not show my placemark icons?

Tags: kml

Here is the [KML](http://www.eklsofttrade.com/lk/android/testkml.kml) file. Only one custom icon is shown at placemark point.

What is the problem with the others?

Comment: I see multiple markers: http://maps.google.com/?q=http://www.eklsofttrade.com/lk/android/testkml.kml Can you be more specific with what you are seeing (device, KML viewer, operating system, etc)

Comment: I use with GoogleEarth this: http://kepfeltoltes.hu/view/120414/kmltest_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg
I don't know why does not show the start, stop, pause icons.
Only show the blue flag. I would like to sign with start icon the start, 1st placemark, with end icon the end of trtack, with pause icon when standing in one place and the speed is zero, and at last with blue flag at the standard placemark
What is the good way to show multiple icons with placemarks in .KML file? (GoogleEarth, Win7, Android 2.2, ZTE-Blade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why does not show the icon image at the placemark except for the blue flag.
All /except for blue flag/ icon URL is begins with "www." instead of "http://www."
It was a basic mistake by myself. :-(